# Traveling abroad with my Ledger

Tags: legal, ledger-hardware-wallet, travel

In the next months I’m going to travel abroad with my Ledger Nano S. I’ll visit most of the EU countries, Russia, China, Brazil, U.S. and Canada. I’m an EU citizen.

I would like to know which is my right to refuse to unlock my Ledger whether I’m intimated to do so by a custom officer.

As far as I know as an EU citizen in the EU *I can refuse* to unlock my devices without violating any law.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong path.

Check the advanced passphrase options. Look for plausible deniability. Add a second wallet with a different PIN and SOME SMALL AMOUNTS. DO NOT rely on being able to refuse unlock unless you are willing to carry the consequences - which may mean spending hours arguing. Much easier to show them some small funds and be done.